# IIS URL Rewrite issue with Tilde (~)

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, sitecore, url-rewrite-module

I have some legacy URLs that I need to redirect that have a tilde (~) as part of the URL.  I'm having some issues getting the IIS Rewrite rules to work.

OLD URL:
http://www.example.com/~/media/something/whatever.pdf

Need it to redirect to:
/whatever

I have the following rules in place:

> Web.Config

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps configSource="RewriteMaps.config" /> 
    <rules configSource="RewriteRules.config" />
</rewrite>
```

> RewriteMaps.config

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Legacy URLS">
        <!--DOES NOT WORK-->
        <add key="~/media/something/whatever.pdf" value="/whatever" />  
        <!--WORKS-->
        <add key="/testing123" value="/whatever" /> 
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

> RewriteRules.config

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Legacy URLS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{Legacy URLS:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Is the tilde `~` really part of the URL (e.g. you actually have a `/~` folder in your server) or is being used in ASP.Net (application) context (to refer to "application root")?

Comment: Unfortunately, for reasons beyond our control, it is part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you must need to escape the tilde, perhaps HTML Encode: 
    `&#126;`

( http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm )   or URL Encode.

Otherwise it must be interpreting ~ differently, a la application home.